# Keeping and enforcing time in MVC 4

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, date, time

I am building an online exam application in MVC 4 (C#), and I am having problems with enforcing a time limit for an exam (duration). The easy way to do it, is to let the server store the start time (in server UTC time), and letting the client calculate the end date using this time stamp converted from UTC. The problem is, that this approach does not consider calendar issues, such as timezones, out-of-sync clocks between server/client, leap years and all that jazz.

Example: a users starts an exam with a 60 min time limit. The server should know the start time (in controller action) and do server side validation at the end of the exam duration. At the same time, the client side should display a countdown (javascript?), and terminate the exam when the limit is reached.

I followed [this example](http://www.prideparrot.com/blog/archive/2011/9/how_to_display_dates_and_times_in_clients_timezone), but it only converts the server time into client time zone. If the client's clock is out of sync, we have a problem. Translating this to my exam environment means that the duration of the exam would not be precisely 60 minutes, it could even be off by +/- hours.

Any ideas about what the best approach might be? Code examples are much appreciated.

Btw, I am pretty new to MVC/javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't agree with your analysis.

I know about physics and relativity and problems of synching clocks, but I think your problem is simple.

The server only has to know about its time.  If a user has X hours to complete a task, all the server has to know is what its local time was when the client initiated the action with first gesture.  X hours from that millisecond and the exam is over.

```
EndTime(Server) = StartTime(Server) + Delta
```

Solve for Delta:

```
Delta = EndTime(Server) - StartTime(Server)
```

The user in another time zone might say that their clock read differently when the exam began, but the delta they experience is the same.

Let's write the same equations from the client's point of view:

```
StartTime(Client) = StartTime(Server) + TimeZoneDelta
EndTime(Client) = EndTime(Server) + TimeZoneDelta
```

Substitute those into the other equation for Delta:

```
Delta = EndTime(Client) - TimeZoneDelta - StartTime(Client) + TimeZoneDelta
Delta = EndTime(Client) - StartTime(Client)
```

*Displaying* dates and times in local time zones is a different matter.  Your article is discussing a different problem.

I can see your client making repeated AJAX calls to the server every minute to find out how much time remains on the test and update a progress bar.  Clients will appreciate the visual feedback, and the server will always send the right answer regardless of the separation between client and server.

Comment: You're right with your analysis that the difference between the two time's doesn't matter. The problem the user described is a scenario where the client via JavaScript uses only the start time from the server and the time available on the local system. To make it not matter and to extend what I think your trying to say is that the server should pass to the client the time remaining at page load and let Javascript count that down and not pass the start date to the client for it to do the calculation

Comment: Yes, exactly.  Don't cross the streams - use either server or client side, but don't mix.

Comment: Quite right you are. Just needed to get a grasp of the situation. I ended up storing UTC server time on exam start, letting the server calculate the time remaining and sending it to the view. The view then displays the timer using only the remaining time. Even work across time zones :) Thanks!